# How to get count of rows based on IF criteria?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a table where I am trying to only count records based on current year. How would I do that in tableau?

`IF (YEAR(TODAY())-1 = YEAR([Start Date])) THEN count([offers]) END`

`offers` is my table name and I just want to count number of instances where todays year (2021) = the year in the `start date` field

but I get a cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate comparisons or results in 'if' expressions error

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(INT(YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR([Start Date]))`

Comment: how would I examine the previous year? I tried appending a `-1` after `today()`, but it's the same exact number as the above calc

Comment: Subtract one from the year, i.e. after, “YEAR(TODAY())” — if you subtract one from today() you get effectively yesterday() :-) which then usually has the same year as today()